# JavaScript Changes My Date Based on Browser Time Zone

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, timezone

I am trying to create a `Date` object in JavaScript, passing a string like this:

> 2014-11-30T00:00:00.0000000

However, the value of the `Date` object is:

> Sat Nov 29 2014 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)

It changed it to 11/29 when I want 11/30. Is there any way I can make the date 2014-11-30, regardless of what time zone the browser is in?

*Note: One possible workaround is to use the `Date(year, month, day)` constructor; however, I am constructing the data in a JSON string, which doesn't appear to support this.*

**EDIT:**

Actually, I just did a test and created a date using `Date(2015, 1, 1)` and it gives me:

> Mon Feb 02 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)

So I can't even create a date that way and have it be the date I want. I don't understand why this is so difficult.

Comment: The string is interpreted in UTC, not your local timezone. You could parse the string yourself, instead of using the built-in datetime parser.

Comment: @Barmar: I thought the 'Z' at the end (which I don't have) specified UTC. At any rate, I'd like this to be part of a JSON string, which doesn't seem to support parsing it myself.

Comment: You can parse it after you decode the JSON.

Comment: @Barmar: Yes, I guess I'm able to do that, although it's rather awkward because I have a whole array of data. So are you saying to parse it myself and then use the year, month, day constructor, as described at the end of my question?

Comment: Yeah, that seems best. ISO date strings are easy to parse with `substr`.

Comment: @Barmar: Actually, I just did a test and created a date using `Date(2015, 1, 1)`, and it gives me "Mon Feb 02 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)". So I can't even create a date that way and have it be the date I want. I don't understand why this is so difficult.

Comment: In Javascript, months start at 0. So 0 = January, 1 = February, etc. You need to subtract 1 before calling `Date()`.

Comment: @Barmar: Oh, right you are. Yes, it does work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Date.UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC)

> The UTC() method differs from the Date constructor in two ways.
>
> - Date.UTC() uses universal time instead of the local time.
> - Date.UTC() returns a time value as a number instead of creating a Date
>     object.

**EDIT** - why does SO insist on making links so hard to spot?  That, up there, is a link to the docs in case that wasn't obvious.

**EDIT 2** - I think I misunderstood.  Try this:

```js
var d = new Date('2014-11-30T00:00:00.0000000'); 
var utc = new Date(
              d.getUTCFullYear(),
              d.getUTCMonth(),
              d.getUTCDate(),
              d.getUTCHours(),
              d.getUTCMinutes(),
              d.getUTCSeconds()
           );
alert('d: ' + d + "\n" + 'utc: ' + utc);
```

Comment: It looks like it's already using universal time. `2014-11-30 00:00 UTC` is `2014-11-29 17:00 MST`.

Comment: Well, first off I think it is already interpreting my time as UTC, no? I guess then I'd need to just convert my original time to UTC and then use that.

Comment: I updated my answer, does that get you what you need?

Comment: Yes, that does appear to work. Perhaps more trouble going that way but that answers the question, thanks.